# Three.js - How to add a clickable shape to a 2D scene with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 2D floorplan drawing made with three.js

I have added the shape in this way:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 90),
    new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 95),
    new THREE.Vector3(74, 0, -50)
);
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000,opacity:0.9 });
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
mesh.on('click', function (ev) {
    console.log(ev);
 });
```

I'm trying to add a shape/geometry, with partial opacity, to the scene and allow the user to click it. On click, I should call a javascript function on the web page retrieving a unique ID and other custom attributes or properties of the clicked shape.

As event manager, I'm using [three.interaction](https://github.com/jasonChen1982/three.interaction.js)

I can't understand where to put the object attributes and retrieve them. Is it possible to do it in three.js?
Is there a way also to style the clickable object on mouseover, like changing its colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved adding the properties in the userData of the object:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 90),
    new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 95),
    new THREE.Vector3(74, 0, -50)
);
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000,opacity:0.9 });
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.userData.code = "12345ABC";
mesh.userData.name = "Example01";
scene.add(mesh);
mesh.on('click', function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.userData.code);
    ev.target.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 );
});
```

I can change also the color with ev.target.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 ); using mouseover and mouseout events.